# Decode JSON from stream of data Docker GO SDK

Tags: docker, go

I want to use [Client.ContainerStats(ctx context.Context, containerID string, stream bool)](https://godoc.org/docker.io/go-docker#Client.ContainerStats) method to get streaming stats of a container.
From what I understand, if I pass `true` to `stream` parameter, Docker will not close connection and periodically sends JSON containing stats of a container. 
However, I don't know how decode JSON because I don't know where JSON data start and end.

What I'm using right now is that I don't use stream option and just fetch data periodically then decode it like this.

```
stats, err := dockerClient.ContainerStats(ctx, container.ContainerID, false)
msgBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(stats.Body)
var containerStats ContainerStats
err = json.Unmarshal(msgBytes, &containerStats)
```

What I'm looking for is a function that block when I call it, then when it receives JSON data (I mean complete JSON data that can be decoded) it will return struct containing data that was decoded from JSON and then I can call that function again to get next stat without having to make a new request to Docker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you have multiple options:

- Map the result on a custom struct
- Map the result on a `map[string]interface{}`

If you want to map by using a custom struct you can do something like this:

```
type myStruct struct {
    Id      string `json:"id"`
    Read    string `json:"read"`
    Preread string `json:"preread"`
}

// perform actions to retrieve logs in stats
//...

var containerStats myStruct
json.NewDecoder(stats.Body).Decode(&containerStats)
fmt.Println(containerStats.Id)
```

With this solution, you have to decide which fields you want to map.

However, if you do not want to specify fields, you can perform something like this:

```
//Perform actions to retrieve logs in stats
//...

var containerStats map[string]interface{}
json.NewDecoder(stats.Body).Decode(&containerStats)
fmt.Println(containerStats["id"])
```

To conclude, if you have to manipulate your data, I recommend you to use the first solution by using custom structure.

---

EDITED: handle stream

By passing `stream` parameter to `true`, the docker api will return an `io.ReadCloser` which will be updated. Then, it's up to the caller to close the `io.ReadCloser` returned.

What you have to do is to perdiodically read the buffer value.

```
type myStruct struct {
    Id       string `json:"id"`
    Read     string `json:"read"`
    Preread  string `json:"preread"`
    CpuStats cpu `json:"cpu_stats"`
}

type cpu struct {
    Usage cpuUsage `json:"cpu_usage"`
}

type cpuUsage struct {
    Total float64 `json:"total_usage"`
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5 * time.Second)
    cli, e := client.NewEnvClient()
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    stats, e := cli.ContainerStats(ctx, "container_id", true)
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("%s", e.Error())
    }
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(stats.Body)
    var containerStats myStruct
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            stats.Body.Close()
            fmt.Println("Stop logging")
            return
        default:
            if err := decoder.Decode(&containerStats); err == io.EOF {
                return
            } else if err != nil {
                cancel()
            }
            fmt.Println(containerStats.CpuStats.Usage.Total)
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, we are decoding the `stats.Body` ReadCloser when new data arrives, printing the total cpu usage, and closing the stream after 5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'm so sorry that my question cause you misunderstand.  I can decode JSON data from response that is not streaming, by streaming I mean Docker will send JSON stats data periodically without closing connection i.e. send data in same connection, and it will close connection only if (from what I understand) container get deleted.  ContainerState is my custom struct that have field match JSON return from [stats API]( https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.32/#operation/ContainerStats) but I didn't know that it have same name as struct in GO SDK.  I updated question.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, in my case I call decode in loop and stop it when receive stop signal.  So, Does it mean that json.Decoder knows where JSON data start and end?, for example, JSON `{"name":"witoong623"}` Does Decoder know that where is "{" at the beginning of JSON and where is "}" at the ending of data and decode right number of bytes?